# Screen Flickers on Razer Stealth

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a Razer Stealth laptop and now I have a terrible screen flickering issue. Everything works normally for about 15 minutes after initial startup then the screen starts to violently flicker every couple seconds with no apparent trigger. I'm really not sure where to start with this issue so any help is greatly appreciated. Here is my system information:

```
H/W path Device Class Description

=================================================

system Blade Stealth (RZ09-02393E32)

/0 bus Blade Stealth

/0/0 memory 64KiB BIOS

/0/25 memory 16GiB System Memory

/0/25/0 memory 8GiB Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuf

/0/25/1 memory [empty]

/0/25/2 memory 8GiB Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous Unbuf

/0/25/3 memory [empty]

/0/2c memory 256KiB L1 cache

/0/2d memory 1MiB L2 cache

/0/2e memory 8MiB L3 cache

/0/2f processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz

/0/100 bridge Intel Corporation

/0/100/2 display Intel Corporation

/0/100/14 bus Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller

/0/100/14/0 usb1 bus xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/14/0/1 multimedia USB Camera

/0/100/14/0/6 communication Bluetooth wireless interface

/0/100/14/0/8 input Razer Blade Stealth

/0/100/14/0/9 input Touchscreen

/0/100/14/1 usb2 bus xHCI Host Controller

/0/100/14.2 generic Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem

/0/100/15 generic Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller

/0/100/15.1 generic Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller

/0/100/16 communication Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1

/0/100/1c bridge Intel Corporation

/0/100/1c/0 wlp1s0 network QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

/0/100/1c.4 bridge Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5

/0/100/1d bridge Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9

/0/100/1d/0 storage Samsung Electronics Co Ltd

/0/100/1f bridge Intel Corporation

/0/100/1f.2 memory Memory controller

/0/100/1f.3 multimedia Intel Corporation

/0/100/1f.4 bus Sunrise Point-LP SMBus


macksol@macksol ~ % lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a list of fixes for this device [here on GitHub](https://github.com/hyphone/razer-stealth-late-2017-kblrefresh-linux/blob/master/README.md)

What fixed this for me was to set `i915.enable_rc6=0` (instead of `1` as the page suggests).

Open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor, for example use

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` and add the parameter between the quotes, do you end up with something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i915.enable_rc6=0 quiet splash"
```

Save and exit, run

```
sudo update-grub
```

And reboot.